# DoctrineModule DoctrineObject hydrator - nested collections are being overwritten

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to hydrate 3 entities using DoctrineModule DoctrineObject hydrator.
I tried to do the same with Stdlib\ObjectProperty hydrator and I got expected, correct results.

First entity:

```
Class Stable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Rider", mappedBy="stable", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $riders;
}
```

Second:

```
Class Rider
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Horse", mappedBy="rider", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $horses;
}
```

Third:

```
Class Horse
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Rider", inversedBy="horses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="horse_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $rider;
}
```

I ommited id properties, getters and setters.

When I hydrate Stable with following data:

```
Stable
  Rider1
    Horse1
    Horse2
  Rider2
    Horse3
  Rider3
    Horse1
    Horse4
```

I get this instead:

```
Stable
  Rider1
    Horse1
    Horse4
  Rider2
    Horse1
    Horse4
  Rider3
    Horse1
    Horse4
```

What is completely wrong. As I've said before when using Stdlib\ObjectProperty hydrator I get the same object relations as in given data.
Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

DoctrineModule docs says:

> Doctrine collections should not be swapped.

It turns out that to get **nested** collections properly hydrated you have to swap them:

```
Class Rider
{
    // model properties

    public function addHorses($horses)
    {
        $this->horses = $horses;
    }

    // other getters and setters
}
```